# Is it possible to loop over flutter cards?

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is what I am trying to do

```
child: FutureBuilder(
         future: ProductRepo().getMyProduct(),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot res){
           if(res.data==null){
             return Container(
                  child: Text('this is nice'),
              );
           }
           return Container(
             child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                      child: Text('I just want to loop over this card :)'),
                  ),

                ],
              )

           );

         }
       ),
```

I always find people looping over listView.builder. Anyone can help, please. Thank you.

Comment: Tbh, it's not clear what you're asking. Where do you want to loop over the cards ? Do you want to transform some sort of list of objects into a list of cards ?

Comment: I have a list of items and I can loop over them using listView.builder so looking if we can do it using card and not a listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a bit of confusion about the use of these widgets.

Indeed both `ListView` and `Column` can be used to display a list of widgets, BUT, `ListView.builder(...)` provides a way to reuse the widgets thus is more memory efficient when you have to create a large number of widgets.

For example, when you want to display a list of electronics for an e-commerce app. For each electronic item you have a photo, title & price, in this case you would want to use a ListView.builder, because the list can be huge and you don't want to run out of memory.

Now on the other hand, the `Column` should be used when you have a small number of widgets that should be displayed in a list-like way (or one beneath the other).

For your case, if you want to transform the list of objects that you have, into a list of cards you can do something like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
         future: ProductRepo().getMyProduct(),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot res){
           if(res.data==null){
             return Container(
                  child: Text('this is nice'),
              );
           }
           return Container(
             child: Column(
                    children: res.data.map((item) {
                                return Card(child: Text(item.name));
                              }).toList());
           );

         }
       ),
```

I've assumed that `res.data` is a list of elements and each element has a property called `name`. Also in the `return Card(...)` line you can do extra processing of the item if you need to do so.

Hope that this can help you :).

**If you have to do more processing**

You can extract the processing in a method or a chain of methods something like this:

````
 List<Widget>prepareCardWidgets(List<SomeObject> theObjects){
 //here you can do any processing you need as long as you return a list of ```Widget```. 
      List<Widget> widgets = [];
      theObjects.forEach((item) {
        widgets.add(Card(child: Text(item.name),));
      });

      return widgets;
    }
````

Then you can use it like this:

```
 FutureBuilder(
             future: ProductRepo().getMyProduct(),
             builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot res){
               if(res.data==null){
                 return Container(
                      child: Text('this is nice'),
                  );
               }
               return Container(
                 child: Column(
                        children: prepareCardWidgets(res.data)
               );

             }
           ),
```

Comment: Nice thanks. How can I do nested loop inside the card?

Comment: ok thanks it works, last few questions, is this the only way of doing it? what if I want to do more nesting loops? For example, lets say facebook status cards, 
Many cards => many comments => many replies. In this case what would be best way of doing it?

Comment: @sadek For that case where you have to do a lot of data processing, you should do it before rendering, flatten your data or create a set of objects that don't need extra processing, only simple checks like, do I display a card like this one or a text or a button. The processing should be done async if you don't want to have a lot of UI lag.

Comment: I cannot think of a flatten data for such a thing... how would you think about such a data structure?